# Salesforce Customer Portal Disabling standard css

Tags: salesforce

I have recently been testing out customer portals on Sites in Salesforce. Ideally I would be able to turn the customer portal off but it appears this isn't possible. I have unticked *login enabled* and removed all associated profiles. But on my sites pages I am still getting the standard portal CSS dumped into the page. I would like to continue using the standard stylesheet.

Does anyone know how stop the portal.css style sheet from running?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a thread that answered this question - note its impossible to delete customer portals at this time. But it can be deactivated. http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Force-com-Sites/How-to-deactivate-customer-portal-in-DE/td-p/159216.

Hope that helps someone.